# Bind the current instance of a control to an attached property

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

I'm looking to see if you can bind the current instance of a usercontrol or window to an attached property defined in its xaml, eg:

```
<Window MyAttachedProp.Value="{Binding Self}"/>
```

Comment: You want the MyAttachedProp.Value to have the Window object reference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want the `MyAttachedProp.Value` to have the `Window` object reference?

You can use any of these methods:

1. `{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}`
2. give your Window an x:Name="XXXXX"...and then use `{Binding ElementName=XXXXX}` to find it.
3. `{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}`
4. `{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}}`

With example 4, it avoids the creation of a new `RelativeSource` object (with the `Mode` set to `Self`)...instead it points to the Static one already created in the `RelativeSource` class....(this is a VERY minor and premature optimization).

Most people use example 3 as it's less to type and clearer to read.

- http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/yougerthen/relativesources-in-wpf/

Answer (score 1):

`{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}`